# Error starting SQL Server configuration manager

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to open SQLSTD configuration file, but can't access it. Anything am doing wrong here? I have all the permission

> Error message when you open SQL Server Configuration Manager in SQL Server: "Cannot connect to WMI provider. You do not have permission or the server is unreachable"

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installation of sql server worked for me

Answer (score 3):

[MS KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/956013/error-message-when-you-open-sql-server-configuration-manager-in-sql-server-cannot-connect-to-wmi-provider.-you-do-not-have-permission-or-the-server-is-unreachable) shows some cause and fixes as well

**Cause:**
This problem occurs because the WMI provider is removed when you uninstall an instance of SQL Server. The 32-bit instance and the 64-bit instance of SQL Server share the same WMI configuration file. This file is located in the %programfiles(x86)% folder.

**Resolution:**

run below commmand in command prompt

> mofcomp "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\number\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

Your number depends on version you are using

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012   110
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2    100
Microsoft SQL Server 2008   100
Microsoft SQL Server 2005   90
```

Comment: I have tried this method and keep getting an error message that says, windows can't open this type of file(.mof)

Comment: can you run from command prompt instead of opening it,also can you check whether do you have file in that location